# What're the standard ways of padding data for GNNs?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, graph-neural-network, pytorch-geometric

I am working on materials property prediction using GNNs with torch_geometric.

Each data in my dataset has different number of feature vectors `x`, edge_index vectors `edge_index`. What I'm doing is to pad all the feature vectors and edge_index features, respectively, to the length of the element with maximum length. For example, this is what I do for the edge_index vector:

```
In:  edge_index = train_set[14].edge_index
     edge_index
Out: tensor([[1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]])
In:  fill_zeros(edge_index, 15, 1)
Out: tensor([[1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

i.e., I defined a function called `fill_zeros` to fill in the dummy variables 0's till the tensor being acted on has length $15$.

However, this incurs many problems when feeding my data into GNN models when doing the message passing. More specifically, when running `propagate()`. I wonder what're the standard ways of padding data for GNN models to avoid such problems?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to **avoid padding** by **batching**.

The idea is that you process data in batches where each Data in the batch has the same amount of feature vectors.

In pytorch_geometric
`from torch_geometric.data import Data, DataLoader`

**Step 1**

Prepare your graph `dataset` as a list of `Data` objects. Each `Data` object should contain a consistent number of nodes and edges.

`dataset = [Data, Data, ...]`

**Step 2**

Sort the `Data` objects in your dataset based on the number of features you want to use for batching. In your case you mentioned edges, so you can use `sort` like this

`dataset.sort(key=lambda data: data.num_edges)`

**Step 3**
Create batches where each batch contains data with the same number of features. You can do this by iterating through the sorted dataset and grouping together graphs with the same feature size.

```
batch_size = 32  # Adjust the batch size as needed
batched_data = []
current_batch = []

for data in dataset:
    # Check if the current data has the same feature size as the data in the current batch
    if not current_batch or data.num_nodes == current_batch[0].num_nodes:
        current_batch.append(data)
    else:
        batched_data.append(current_batch)
        current_batch = [data]

# Append the last batch
if current_batch:
    batched_data.append(current_batch)
```

**Step 4**

Create a `DataLoader` from the `batched_data` list

`data_loader = DataLoader(batched_data, batch_size=None, shuffle=True)`

note: `batch_size` is set to None because you've already grouped the data into batches.

With this setup, each batch in the `DataLoader` will contain `Data` objects with the same number of features, ensuring that you don't need to perform any padding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. This is very useful. But this might not be applicable for my case. The data in my dataset are mostly different in terms of lengths of feature vectors and edge indices.

Also, I wonder where you used the variable ```batch_size = 32``` and how this would enable the model to train batches with different sizes? Shall we create a new model for every batch?